# I am getting this error when I am using Screen Manager: kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "display"

Tags: python, kivy

I am making an application using Screen Manager in kivy and I am stuck here. I am new to kivy and python. as far as I know I am doing everything correctly.

error says-

> kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name
>   "display"

Note: this is only a part of my code for the sake of simplicity I am only showing the lines where the error is occuring.

```
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.10.0')

    from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label 
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup  
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
    from kivy.lang import Builder 
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty


    import json

    Builder.load_file('VocabularyJournal.kv')

    class MenuPage(Screen, StackLayout):
        pass

    class DisplayPage(Screen, BoxLayout):



        def __init__(self, *args):# the error occured after I wrote these line before that every other screens were working properly.
            BoxLayout.__init__(self,*args)
            with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
                data=json.load(rfile)

            #some codes here

    class WordInsertPage(Screen,FloatLayout):
        pass


    class NewWordPage(Screen,StackLayout):
        pass

    class FlashCard(Screen):
        pass

    class WordGroups(Screen):
        pass

    sm=ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(MenuPage(name='menu'))
    sm.add_widget(WordInsertPage(name='insertword'))
    sm.add_widget(NewWordPage(name='newword'))
    sm.add_widget(FlashCard(name='flashcard'))
    sm.add_widget(WordGroups(name='wordgroup'))
    sm.add_widget(DisplayPage(name='display'))

    class VocabularyJournalApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return sm

    object = VocabularyJournalApp()
    object.run()
```

heres the part of kv file where the error is occuring:

```
    # the part of the code where the error is occuring

    <WordInsertPage>:

        FloatLayout:

            Button: 
                text: "New Word"
                on_press: root.manager.current='newword'# this is working very well
                font_size: 30
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: .2, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.3}
                background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
            Button:
                text: "search word"
                on_press: root.manager.current='display' # here the error says kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "display".

                font_size: 30
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: .2, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.5}
                background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
            Button:
                text: 'Flash Cards'
                on_press: root.manager.current="flashcard"
                font_size: 30
                color: 0,0,0,1
                size_hint: .2, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.7}
                background_down: 'darkgrey.png'
```

here is the traceback:

```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\HP\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-03-01_31.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
    [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.4.0 - Build 21.20.16.4627'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 4
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.40 - Build 21.20.16.4627'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
    [INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <b"WARNING: 0:7: '' :  #version directive missing">
    [INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <b"WARNING: 0:7: '' :  #version directive missing">
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
    [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] not enough space for displaying all children
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] need 176px, got 100px
    [WARNING] [Accordion   ] layout aborted.
    [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "E:\SharanyaPy\desktop vocabulary journal\vocabJournal.py", line 92, in <module>
         object.run()
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
         runTouchApp()
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
         EventLoop.window.mainloop()
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 663, in mainloop
         self._mainloop()
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 405, in _mainloop
         EventLoop.idle()
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
         self.dispatch_input()
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
         post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
         listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1188, in on_motion
         self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1204, in on_touch_down
         if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1189, in on_touch_down
         return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
         if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
         ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
         if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 457, in on_touch_down
         if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8191)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
         self.dispatch('on_press')
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8146)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1109, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12816)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
         exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
       File "E:\SharanyaPy\desktop vocabulary journal\VocabularyJournal.kv", line 51, in <module>
         on_press: root.manager.current='display'
       File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (kivy\properties.c:5572)
       File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set (kivy\properties.c:6405)
       File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (kivy\properties.c:7105)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
       File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1131, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:13193)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1037, in on_current
         screen = self.get_screen(value)
       File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1063, in get_screen
         raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
     kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "display".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DisplayPage` class you are overwriting the `__init__` method, so you need to call the `__init__` method of the parent (`Screen` class). With `BoxLayout.__ init __ (self, * args)` you just call the constructor of  `BoxLayout`but not the constructor of `Screen`. I don't understand why you try to do a multiple subclassing here, you can simply inherit from `Screen` and call its constructor (preferably using `super`).

`Screen` is a `RelativeLayout`, if you need to use another layout in your screen simply add it as any widget (being careful with certain [peculiarities](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#kivy-uix-relativelayout-common-pitfalls)):

```
<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        # Rest of screen's content here
```

You can do something like:

**main.py:**

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

import json



Builder.load_file('VocabularyJournal.kv')


class MenuPage(Screen):
    pass


class DisplayPage(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Call __init__ method of parent class (Screen)
        super(DisplayPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)  
        with open('vocab_words.json') as rfile:
            data = json.load(rfile)


class WordInsertPage(Screen):
    pass


class NewWordPage(Screen):
    pass


class FlashCard(Screen):
    pass


class WordGroups(Screen):
    pass


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class VocabularyJournalApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    object = VocabularyJournalApp()
    object.run()
```

**VocabularyJournal.kv:**

```
<Manager>:
    MenuPage:
        name: 'menu'
    WordInsertPage:
        name: 'insertword'
    NewWordPage:
        name: 'newword'
    FlashCard:
        name: 'flashcard'
    WordGroups:
        name: 'wordgroup'
    DisplayPage:
        name: 'display'


<MenuPage>:
    # Your code here


<WordInsertPage>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: "New Word"
            on_press: root.manager.current='newword'
            font_size: 30
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.3}
        Button:
            text: "search word"
            on_press: root.manager.current='display'

            font_size: 30
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.5}
        Button:
            text: 'Flash Cards'
            on_press: root.manager.current="flashcard"
            font_size: 30
            color: 0,0,0,1
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.7}



<NewWordPage>:
    # Your code here

<FlashCard>:
    # Your code here

<WordGroups>:
    # Your code here

<DisplayPage>:
    # Your code here
```

> **Note:** if you rename your kv as `vocabularyjournal.kv` you do not need to use `Builder.load_file`: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv

Comment: @Sri991  What is the error? The code above has been tested in Python 3.6 and Kivy 1.10